# jQuery .ajax Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve data through .ajax call and add the response html code to bootstrap modal body. But I kept receiving this error:

jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://localhost/menu/create

Actually I do receive the desired data in response, but because of this error, the data cannot be displayed on modal window.

Here is my code. When I click a link, the ajax call returns a html form and inserts it into modal body. Then the modal window is shown.

```
<a href="{{route('menu.create')}}" class="btn btn-default pull-right show-new-menu-item-modal" data-toggle="modal">New Menu Item</a>

$('body').on('click', '.show-new-menu-item-modal', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {
            $("#new-menu-item-body").html(response);
        }
    });
    $('#new-menu-item-modal').modal('show');
});
```

I have been googling and changing the code for several hours but still no luck. I would highly appreciate it if anyone can give me some idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to add return false at the end of your ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is due to bootstrap and the fact you have set `data-toggle="modal"` on the element.

Try removing that. You are initializing the modal yourself as it is.

What I think is happening is because you didn't use the `data-target` that is required in association with `data-toggle` it is trying to use the `href` as a jQuery selector for the modal id and that would throw the error you see if you did that

Answer (score 0):

@charlietfl is right, you cannot prevent the default action to a modal, if you do that, it will not open at all, check the javascript way of invoking a modal in the Bootstrap documentation, it has a fix that you can use to make what you want, check this url: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/.

Hope you solve

Bests!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Bootstrap model and are getting a syntax error, ensure the returned HTML does not have whitespace before the first DOM node.